# Multiple jquery causing conflict couldn't resolve

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery for two purposes . One for adding a calender. other for toggling between tags. But when put together only 1 is working . If i comment 1st script second one is working and if i comment 2nd script 1st  one is working.

## New Update

Here's the script for calender.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
$("#pickdate").datepicker({
buttonImage: 'images/date.jpg',
buttonImageOnly: true,
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
showOn: 'both',
});
});
</script>
```

for this

```
  <div class="date">Due date  <input id="pickdate" type="text" placeholder="select" /></div>
```

Here's script for toggling tabs.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".pro").click(function(){
$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
});
});
</script>
```

for this one

```
<ul class="promenu">
<li class="pro" > <a href="#">One-Time</a> </li>
<li class="pro selected" > <a href="#">Recurring</a> </li>
</ul>
.pro a{
display: block;
padding: 3px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;       
}
.selected{
background:#47ABCC;
}
.promenu .selected a{
color:#fff;
background:#47ABCC;
}
```

how to resolve this.?

Comment: You should only add jquery once, if you add it two or more times it will override previously added jquery files, It would be useful if you add latest version of jquery, if you want to chose between two

Comment: did u try jquery no conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to include a reference to jQuery once per script tag, you only need it once.

So in this case, I'd say remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>` and keep the reference to version 1.10.2. You can also keep the reference to jQuery UI.

Comment: Give me the whole code, I mean also HTML. I will make that work for you.

Comment: No @Chipowski this link gives stle to calender. all must have to be there i cant remove them

Comment: @Sharefun No I'm not asking you to remove the reference to the CSS (the <link> tag) but one of the references to jQuery.js.
You only need one of them to function, and since both of your scripts that depend on jQuery executes after different versions of jQuery has loaded, one of the scripts will conflict.

So, **keep** jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.js, and **keep** jquery-1.10.2, but **remove** jquery-1.6.2.js.

Comment: The first three cannot be removed i tried and it dint worked out. @Chipowski

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you read my entire comment.
Simply put: in the first code block you posted, keep ALL code since it contains latest jquery, jquery UI and related CSS.

In the **second** code block, remove the first reference to jquery since your **first** code block **already references** jquery.

Read my answer carefully, I'm showing **exactly** which line of code you should remove.

Comment: @Sharefun Thank you for providing more code, however it doesn't really add much. The problem here is the duplicate references to jQuery, and the order of code execution.

Comment: oh god that was so simple thank you and sorry for this lame ques actually i dint tried the order. and thankyou again that helped alot .